# Get div to take up 100% body height, minus fixed-height header and footer

Tags: css

From my research, this appears to be an absolutely classic CSS question, but I can't find a definitive answer - so StackOverflow it is.

How do I set a content div to take up 100% of the body height, minus the height taken up by a fixed-height header and footer?

```html
<body>
  <header>title etc</header>
  <div id="content">body content</div>
  <footer>copyright etc</footer>
</body>

//CSS
html, body { 
  height: 100%;
}
header { 
  height: 50px;
}
footer { 
  height: 50px;
}
#content { 
  height: 100% of the body height, minus header & footer
}
```

I would like to use pure CSS, and for the answer to be bulletproof across browsers.

Comment: what do you want to happen if the #content is larger than the viewport? do you want the footer to be pushed down or would you like the content to scroll?

Comment: I'd like the footer to be pushed down, thank you.

Comment: when you say cross browser, is that all the latest browsers or does it have to work for older versions of ie too

Comment: IE8 is a must. IE7 and older are not.

Comment: Have added an answer that is compatible for all new browsers and ie8

Answer (score 67, accepted):

this version will work in all the latest browsers and ie8 if you have the modernizr script (if not just change `header` and `footer` into `div`s):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naqE6/1/)

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  padding: 50px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#content {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

header {
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

footer {
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>dfs</header>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <footer>sdf</footer>
</div>
```

Scrolling with content:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naqE6/)

Comment: As this answer seems to be being hit a lot I thought I should also give [a link to this answer as it has some alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651942/css-single-column-layout-centered-fixed-width-100-height-w-header-and-footer/23657083#23657083)

Comment: Running the jsfiddle demo makes the header and footer scroll. From the question, I understand that the requirement is to have the header/footer shown even when the content is scrollable.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka did you read the comments too? I asked the questions that lead me to this answer which was accepted over 2 years ago

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Besides as this question is so old, it is pretty out of date and I would go with using display flex now as the support for that is now all major browsers, where as when this was answered, flex had quite limited support

Comment: Definitively that is not an answer event 2 years ago.... what is the point of having fixed divs thats scrolls when the content have to have to be scrolled.

Answer (score 40):

As far as it is not cross browser solution, you might be take advantage of using `calc(expression)` to achive that.

```
html, body { 
 height: 100%;
}
header {        
 height: 50px;
 background-color: tomato
}

#content { 
 height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px); /* Firefox */
 height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px); /* Chrome, Safari */
 height: calc(100% - 100px); /* IE9+ and future browsers */
 background-color: yellow 
}
footer { 
 height: 50px;
 background-color: grey;
}
```

[Example at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/y3U8F/1/)

If you want to know more about `calc(expression)` you'd better to visit [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-calc-function/) site.

Comment: I wanted to just mention something for this solution. when using calc with height, it will be the calculated height of that element when the page loads. if your content container expands from loading some dynamic content, the overflow will be visible, which is fine, but if you are wanting to set a background color on the #content element, make it min-height instead of height so it will always expand content correctly.

Answer (score 32):

This still came up as the top Google result when I was trying to find an answer to this question.  I didn't have to support older browsers in my project and I feel like I found a better, simpler solution in [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).  The CSS snippet below is all that is necessary.

I have also shown how to make the main content scrollable if the screen height is too small.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  min-height: 60px;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
footer {
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0px; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 18px;">
  <header style="background-color: lightsteelblue; padding: 2px;">Hello</header>
  <main style="overflow: auto; background-color: lightgrey; padding: 2px;">
    <article style="height: 400px;">
      Goodbye
    </article>
  </main>
  <footer style="background-color: lightsteelblue; padding: 2px;">I don't know why you say, "Goodbye"; I say, "Hello."</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, as if "flex", "flex-grow", and "flex-direction" -- names that open a whole black box full of behavior -- is more clear than a simple vertical offset.  I'll stick with the negative margins.

Comment: @Triynko, I agree that using negative margins is a fine solution, but it didn't fit my needs.  The solution I provided has the advantage of always having the header and footer shown on the page and the rest of the content filling the screen and being scrollable.

Comment: This is the method of the future.  No need to know the exact height of your header/footer either. Percentages are now possible.

Comment: Currently most browsers support flex. I think I'll go with this solution. Due to responsiveness this seems the best solution

Comment: The `main` element in my app is extending beyond the footer and scrolling when the content height is much smaller than the `main` element. I see that the snippet is able to render the `main` element with a height that fills the viewport without scrolling. Are there any pointers on debugging a flexbox that isn't sizing the elements as expected?

Comment: @John, Without being able to see what you have it's difficult to know for sure. For flexbox elements that are not sizing as expected I would scrutinize the flex-basis, flex-grow, and flex-shrink properties -- or just flex, which can incorporate all 3 -- on the child element which is not the expected size, your main in this case.
I included this above, but I'll include it again here, CSS-Tricks' Complete Guide To Flexbox is a Godsend. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Still having trouble? Re-create the bare minimum in Codepen and post a link. https://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 19):

The new, modern way to do this is to calculate the vertical height by subtracting the height of both the header and the footer from the vertical-height of the viewport.

```
//CSS
header { 
  height: 50px;
}
footer { 
  height: 50px;
}
#content { 
  height: calc(100vh - 50px - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Compatible from IE 9 upwards. What is vh?

Comment: Great, simple solution (using calc).  I'll also point out that calc can work with % values in addition to vh and vw.

Comment: vh is viewport height and vw is viewport width.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to calculate the header and footer is bad :( A design should be simple, self explanatory. Plain easy. Calculations are just...not easy. Not easy for human and a bit hard on machines.

What you're looking for is a subset of the [Holy Grail design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Grail_(web_design)).

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/swHKE2?p=preview)'s an implementation using the flex display. It includes side bars in addition to the footer and header. Enjoy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Holy Grail</title>
    <!-- Reset browser defaults -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  </head>
  <body style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
    <div>HEADER<br/>------------
    </div>
    <!-- No need for 'flex-direction: row' because it's the default value -->
    <div style="display: flex; flex: 1">
      <div>NAV|</div>
      <div style="flex: 1; overflow: auto">
        CONTENT - START<br/>
        <script>
        for (var i=0 ; i<1000 ; ++i) {
          document.write(" Very long content!");
        }
        </script>
        <br/>CONTENT - END
      </div>
      <div>|SIDE</div>
    </div>
    <div>------------<br/>FOOTER</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 2.5 years after the question was asked, hope the requirements now allow IE10: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can take advatange of the css property [Box Sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

```
#content { 
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

See the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Hqm5/).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work with lots of body content: http://jsfiddle.net/8Hqm5/1/ I think @Pete's solution is better for handling cases where the size of the body content is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been pretty well answered, but I'm taking the liberty of adding a javascript solution.  Just give the  element that you want to 'expand' the id `footerspacerdiv`, and this javascript snippet will expand that div until the page takes up the full height of the browser window.

It works based on the observation that, when a page is less than the full height of the browser window, document.body.scrollHeight is equal to document.body.clientHeight.  The while loop increases the height of `footerspacerdiv` until document.body.scrollHeight is greater than document.body.clientHeight.  At this point, `footerspacerdiv` will actually be 1 pixel too tall, and the browser will show a vertical scroll bar.  So, the last line of the script reduces the height of `footerspacerdiv` by one pixel to make the page height exactly the height of the browser window.

By placing `footerspacerdiv` just above the 'footer' of the page, this script can be used to 'push the footer down' to the bottom of the page, so that on short pages, the footer is flush with the bottom of the browser window.

```
<script>    
//expand footerspacer div so that footer goes to bottom of page on short pages        
  var objSpacerDiv=document.getElementById('footerspacer');          
  var bresize=0;   

  while(document.body.scrollHeight<=document.body.clientHeight) {
    objSpacerDiv.style.height=(objSpacerDiv.clientHeight+1)+"px";
    bresize=1;
  }             
  if(bresize) { objSpacerDiv.style.height=(objSpacerDiv.clientHeight-1)+"px"; }               
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't use negative margins or `calc`. Run the snippet below to see the final result.

**Explanation**

We give the header and the footer a fixed height of `30px` and position them absolutely at the top and bottom, respectively. To prevent the content from falling underneath, we use two classes: `below-header` and `above-footer` to pad the div above and below with `30px`.

All of the content is wrapped in a `position: relative` div so that the header and footer are at the top/bottom of the *content* and not the window.

We use the classes `fit-to-parent` and `min-fit-to-parent` to make the content fill out the page. This gives us a sticky footer which is at least as low as the window, but hidden if the content is longer than the window.

Inside the header and footer, we use the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` styles to give the header and footer some vertical padding without disrupting the shrink-wrap quality of the page. (Giving them real padding can cause the total height of the page to be more than `100%`, which causes a scroll bar to appear when it isn't really needed.)

```css
.fit-parent {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.min-fit-parent {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.below-header {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.above-footer {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* helper classes */

.padding-lr-small {
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.auto-scroll {
  overflow: auto;
}
/* these two classes work together to create vertical centering */
.valign-outer {
    display: table;
}
.valign-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html class='fit-parent'>
  <body class='fit-parent'>
<div class='min-fit-parent auto-scroll relative' style='background-color: lightblue'>
<div class='header valign-outer' style='background-color: black; color: white;'>
        <div class='valign-inner padding-lr-small'>
            My webpage
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='fit-parent above-footer below-header'>
        <div class='fit-parent' id='main-inner'>
          Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding
          dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris
          finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum
          doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem
          ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory
          Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding
          dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris
          finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum
          doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem
          ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory
          Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding
          dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris
          finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum
          doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem
          ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory
          Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding
          dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris
          finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum
          doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem
          ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory
          Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding
          dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris
          finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum
          doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem
          ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory
          Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding
          dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris
          finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum
          doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem
          ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory
          Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding
          dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris
          finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum
          doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem
          ipsum doloris finding dory Lorem ipsum doloris finding dory
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='footer valign-outer' style='background-color: white'>
        <div class='valign-inner padding-lr-small'>
            &copy; 2005 Old Web Design
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```