# How to remove this extra space at the bottom of the HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page whose structure is like this -

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">...</div>
    <div id="in-body">...</div>
    <div id="footer">...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My aim is to make the `#header` & `#footer` static at top & bottom of the page, respectively, but there is always some space left after the `#footer`.

I thought if adding the % `height`s of the `div`s will give `100%`, I could cover the whole `body` area, but still even as of now I'm using `(18 + 75 + 3)% = 96%` of the `height`, there is still some space left after the `#footer`.

The CSS for this is -

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 97.9%;
    margin: 8px 8px 0px 8px;
}

#header {
    height: 18%;
    margin: 0;
}

#in-body {
    height: 75%;
    margin: 0;
}

#footer {
    height: 3%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I've checked from Chrome's Developer Tools that there is no extra `margin` or `padding` anywhere.

If I try to make the addition `100%`, a scroll bar appears, and there is still that space left, which doesn't belong to any element (from Chrome Developer Tools), not even `html`, but it remains just there.

I've used `body-height: 97.9%` because I only want all the visible `html-height` without overflow.

I've checked this in IE11, Chrome 50 and Firefox 46, and it is the same in all.

Keeping `html { overflow: hidden }` hides it in IE & Firefox, but not in Chrome.

What is causing this? Is there any way other than using `overflow` to remove it?

If I'm wrong in my approach anywhere, feel free to correct me.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/en3esh2y/1/)'s the complete code.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I tested the code mentioned above with each tag having a different bg-color and it works fine. So, it is my code that is causing the trouble. Help me, please.

Comment: `body { padding: 0; }`. You have the margin of the bottom to zero, but not the padding.

Comment: As I've written, there is no extra `padding` or `margin` in any element that is causing this. I've checked for all of them.

Comment: Can you add a working example? You are not telling all the truth. When you remove padding and margin from `html`  and `body` tags, you'll obtain no space. I think you have more code making conflicts. Share a working fiddle (stacksnippets or jsfiddle.net for example) reproducing the problem, and we'll see what's the issue.

Comment: Do you just need to move the footer at the bottom most part of the page? A fiddle will help to understand your question.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I tested the code mentioned in question with each tag having a different bg-color and it works fine. So, it is my code that is causing the trouble.

Comment: There will be space after your footer because your `body`'s height isn't 100% - and then your three elements don't add up to 100% - in effect your elements add up to 96% of 97.9% of the document height

Comment: One thing that breaks your wanted layout (apart from what @Pete is saying above) is <br> you have after footer element in your code, so remove it and see if you get what you wanted.

Comment: @fbxmg That did it, my bad. You can add that as answer. Can somebody close this question?

Comment: @PalashV as I tell you, when you share the fiddle automatically you receive the solution. Remove the <br> tag. It's because it's important to share a working fiddle reproducing the issue (read the help center to more info). I vote to close this as typographical error. Good luck!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Sorry for the trouble. It is my 2nd time with html. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/en3esh2y/2/

Comment: @PalashV don't worry, you're welcome :) See you soon!

Comment: If you are just wanting a sticky footer though, I would recommend against using the percentages like you have done, as if you height gets smaller, then your header and footer get smaller (and may break the layout of your page).  Have a look at my answer here for ways to do a sticky footer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651942/css-single-column-layout-centered-fixed-width-100-height-w-header-and-footer/23657083#23657083

Comment: @Pete Nice! I'll include this for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the calc() method in CSS3 to make sure there is no difference when using % and px together.

So your body class can be:

```
body
{
    height: calc(100% - 8px);
    margin: 8px 8px 0px 8px;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't this be 100% - 8px?

Comment: @Pete Yup, cause that `8px` belong to the `margin-up` to be removed from `100%`.