# CSS: how to attach footer to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I want to attach Footer to the bottom of the page. To do so I used Absolute position in css as recommended in other similar topics. But for unknown reason the footer behaves as if it is Fixed, not Absolute.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header {
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

main {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

footer {
  border-top: solid 1px;
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    This is header
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sunt, eaque optio id nostrum ullam voluptatum incidunt modi autem nulla nihil, voluptatibus iusto consectetur. Est quas libero illum dolore dicta?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sunt, eaque optio id nostrum ullam voluptatum incidunt modi autem nulla nihil, voluptatibus iusto consectetur. Est quas libero illum dolore dicta?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sunt, eaque optio id nostrum ullam voluptatum incidunt modi autem nulla nihil, voluptatibus iusto consectetur. Est quas libero illum dolore dicta?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sunt, eaque optio id nostrum ullam voluptatum incidunt modi autem nulla nihil, voluptatibus iusto consectetur. Est quas libero illum dolore dicta?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sunt, eaque optio id nostrum ullam voluptatum incidunt modi autem nulla nihil, voluptatibus iusto consectetur. Est quas libero illum dolore dicta?</p>
  </main>

  <footer>
    This is footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Screen 1: [image]
Screen 2: [image]

The footer should stick with the lower edge of the page, instead it remains stick with the lower edge of the browser. What's wrong?

Comment: Why not just use `position: relative`?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/o5aTdu4iLGSVIWxi3sUu Check this out. Just remove 3 CSS rules and let footer move naturally to the bottom of the page

Comment: @thebluefox because if the content doesn't fill the screen, then the footer won't be at the bottom of the viewport, I think OP is wanting a sticky footer that will be at the bottom of the content or bottom of the screen, whichever is bigger

Comment: @Pete I missed that requirement - good answer below.

Comment: @sva605 although my answer below answers this question, it may cause you issues as you will need to add bottom padding to the body for the height of the footer (otherwise your footer may overlap some content) - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651942/css-single-column-layout-centered-fixed-width-100-height-w-header-and-footer/23657083#23657083) for some good alternates for how to do a sticky footer depending on what browsers you need to support:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have set a height of 100% on your body, therefore your body will only ever be as high as the viewport. Try using `min-height` for the body (also add position relative to body):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header {
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

main {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

footer {
  border-top: solid 1px;
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    This is header
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sunt, eaque optio id nostrum ullam voluptatum incidunt modi autem nulla nihil, voluptatibus iusto consectetur. Est quas libero illum dolore dicta?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sunt, eaque optio id nostrum ullam voluptatum incidunt modi autem nulla nihil, voluptatibus iusto consectetur. Est quas libero illum dolore dicta?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sunt, eaque optio id nostrum ullam voluptatum incidunt modi autem nulla nihil, voluptatibus iusto consectetur. Est quas libero illum dolore dicta?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sunt, eaque optio id nostrum ullam voluptatum incidunt modi autem nulla nihil, voluptatibus iusto consectetur. Est quas libero illum dolore dicta?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sunt, eaque optio id nostrum ullam voluptatum incidunt modi autem nulla nihil, voluptatibus iusto consectetur. Est quas libero illum dolore dicta?</p>
  </main>

  <footer>
    This is footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can use flexbox, than that is your solution. Look here on the css tricks - you don't need more. https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify the **position** for footer, also remove the bottom and left. You need to specify the **height**(in %) of every section. Try with below CSS,

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 20px;
}

header {
 height:10%;
 background: rgba(150,150,150,0.5);
 border-bottom: solid 1px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

main {
height:80%;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-right: 100px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
}

footer {
height:10%;
border-top: solid 1px;
background: rgba(150,150,150,0.5);
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
padding-top: 10px;
text-align: center;   
}
```

Here, if the screen size in big or if someone zoom out the screen or if content in the page is very less, the footer will always remain at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to do that is via flex.

Ensure body/root or whatever is the 100% container is `display:flex`
You can make it more or less not impactful depending on rest of your CSS by using `flex-direction:column`.

Once that's done create a footer container by something like-

```
<div id="footer">
   <span>my footer text </span>
<div>
```

Now make this container column flexbox as well with `flex-grow:2` which ensures it will consume all of the remaining vertical space. Then justify the content to flex end such that it will stick to the bottom.

```
#footer {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-grow: 2;
}
```

This ensures if the content doesn't cover full height, footer stays at bottom. If content is bigger than viewport height, it scolls and stays at the end of content without additional space.

Everything together -

```css
html {
  height:90% /* quiriness of iframe used here */
}

body {
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#footer {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-grow:2;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello World
</div>


<div id="footer">
  <span>my footer<span>
</div>
```