# Use window.innerHeight to set div height in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have three `div` elements (header, middle and footer) and I want to fix the header and the footer to height of 100px, and the middle to have a dynamic height per the window inner height.

I tried the following without success:

```
<div id="header" style="background-color:white;width:100px; height:12vh; margin: 0; padding: 0 ;border:0;"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="background-color:black;width:window.innerHeight-200;height:78vh;margin: 0; padding: 0 ;border:0"></div>
<div id="footer" style="background-color:white;width:100px; height:10vh; margin: 0; padding: 0 ;border:0;bottom:0px"></div>
```

Comment: do u think window.innerHeight is a css property??

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: get div to take up 100% body height, minus fixed-height header and footer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021573/css-get-div-to-take-up-100-body-height-minus-fixed-height-header-and-footer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`window.innerHeight` is JavaScript, *not* CSS.

If you want your `#map_canvas` element to have a width of `100vh` (see [Viewport-percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)) minus 200px you can use [CSS's `calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="...width: calc(100vh - 200px);..."></div>
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wZ3Eu/1/).

Ideally you shouldn't be using inline styles though. You should move your styles into [a stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html):

```css
div#map_canvas {
    ...
    width: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

I have a feeling you may have wanted to do this for the `height` though, and not the `width`... In that case simply change `width` above to `height`.

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="...height: calc(100vh - 200px);..."></div>
```

[**JSFiddle demo using `height` instead of `width`**](http://jsfiddle.net/wZ3Eu/2/).

Comment: Many thanks! Was the function calc that was missing.

Comment: Have in mind that `vh` is not supported by Safari, Firefox and IE.

Comment: Just to notice that `vh` could be a mess if you are letting your user expand or reduce their address bar in mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

are you expecting like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>InnerHeight</title>
    <style>
    #header{
        height: 100px;
    }
    #content{
        background: gray;

    }
    #footer{
        height: 100px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='content'></div>
<div id='footer'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#content').css('height',$(document).innerHeight()+200)
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```