# fill div height with remaining space ( only CSS and cross browser solution: no calc() )

Tags: html, css

I know there are plenty of similar question, but i'm looking for a cross-browser approach with pure CSS (not JS).

I have 3 div ([Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/peg0e1pq/)):

1. **Top**

   `#top{ height: 100px; }`
2. **Bottom**

   `#bottom{ height: 50px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; }`
3. **Middle** div, that should take all the remaining space

   `#middle{ height: calc(100% - 150px); }`

This is working exactly as i want, but unfortunaly calc() is not supported in all browsers, as we can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

So, what should i use instead? (only CSS, not JS)

Comment: you will need to use JS or `position:fixed` and position it accordingly

Comment: `calc` is pure CSS..and it's good for the last three versions of IE.

Comment: well you can always use padding-top:100px; padding-bottom:50px; height:100%;

Comment: As you correctly point, `calc()` is actually cross-browser but not supported by older versions. I presume you want to target IE8. IN that case, would the suggestion of caniuse to use `expression()` be a possibility ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: get div to take up 100% body height, minus fixed-height header and footer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021573/css-get-div-to-take-up-100-body-height-minus-fixed-height-header-and-footer)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/peg0e1pq/2/ something like this with position:fixed

Comment: This is a basic "sticky footer" question, for which there are many CSS solutions covering browsers including IE6. Make friends with Google (and forget `position: absolute`).

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes you are just converting div's px height in an arbitrary percentage and making subtraction, that's not what i wanted.

Comment: @himanshu padding would be included in the scrollable content, isn't it?

Comment: @Bartdude exactly, overall android browsers so i guess can't use it, thanks anyway.