# min-height not working on the body

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with `min-height: 100%`

I want the footer always below my content. Meaning, if the content is longer than the screen height, you don't see the footer, until you've scrolled all the way to the bottom

Also, when the content is shorter than the screen height, the footer needs to be at the bottom of the screen. Well, I thought I solved this just by adding `min-height: 100%`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body, main { min-height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <article> .... </article>
            <footer> ... </footer>
        </main>
    </body>
</htm>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/np9n4ckb/1/)

Now, for some reason the `body` tag seems to ignore this setting and its height simply fits the content.

Unfortunately, you can't just set the body to 100% ( [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/np9n4ckb/2/) )

Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: get div to take up 100% body height, minus fixed-height header and footer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021573/css-get-div-to-take-up-100-body-height-minus-fixed-height-header-and-footer) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651942/css-single-column-layout-centered-fixed-width-100-height-w-header-and-footer/23657083#23657083 for newer answer

Comment: The accepted answer will not work in IE10 and lower... http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It will needs prefixes!

Comment: But I must add that I still don't understand why my demo doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` for this:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%
}

main {
  min-height:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background:blue;
}

article {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background:green;
}

footer {
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>... </article>
  <footer> ... </footer>
</main>
```

Comment: This will not work in IE10 and lower... http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: @Legionar should work in ie10 - may need vendor prefixes though: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex  Also no need for the downvote - the question doesn't stipulate which browser this needs to work for and as far as I can see, mine is the only one that allows for a variable height footer.  Besides, if you need it to work in ie9 or lower, I have given a couple of links in the comments that have answers that will work in ie9 and lower

Comment: So just please add that prefixes, and I will agree with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sticky footer `'hack'` is usually done with the `min-height` and negative `margin-bottom` on the footer parent element. All parent elements up until root `html`, need to have `height:100%;`

```
article{
  //height: calc(100% - 50px);
  min-height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-bottom:-50px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE LONG CONTENT](http://jsfiddle.net/np9n4ckb/11/)

[JSFIDDLE SHORT CONTENT](http://jsfiddle.net/np9n4ckb/12/)

Answer (score 3):

The fantastic [**CSS Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/) website has, in their [Snippets](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/) area a snippet for a Sticky Footer:

> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Or using jQuery:

> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/

*latest link with demo*

Or you can simply use Modern Clean CSS “Sticky Footer” from [James Dean](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/)

So just change your HTML and CSS to this:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <article> .... </article>
    </main>
    <footer> ... </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo here](http://mystrd.at/data/sticky_footer.html)

Answer (score 1):

I modified your css to put the footer and the article in a relative position:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

article {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  position: relative;
}

main {
  background-color:lightgray;
}
footer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/np9n4ckb/5/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess with positioning, you can use `vh` units.
`1vh` equals 1% of the viewport's height.

(For reference, this is a good read: https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/np9n4ckb/6/

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  min-height: 100vh; /* Minimum height is the full viewport */
}

article {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px); /* Minimum height is the viewport height minus the footer */
}

main {
  background-color:lightgray;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* browser reset */

html {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%: padding-bottom: 50px;
  /* equal to footer height */
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
header {
  background: #333;
}
main {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>Menu</header>
  <main>content of unknown height!!</main>
  <footer>footer always stays at bottom</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

This is just what you need to do.