# Full width and height empty state?

Tags: css, polymer, material-design, polymer-1.0

Trying to make an empty state placed below an `app-header`. I want it to take the full width and full height (minus the height of the `app-header`) of the entire screen.

So far, I have this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<app-header-layout>
    <app-header>
        .....
    </app-header>
    <div id="empty-state" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #F00; white-space: nowrap;">
        .....
    </div>
</app-header-layout>
```

Still no go. The empty state has the full width that I want, but not the height that I want.

Please help me out.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple way to do this. You can use a [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021573/get-div-to-take-up-100-body-height-minus-fixed-height-header-and-footer)):

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
app-header {
  min-height: 50px;
}
#empty-state {
  overflow: auto;
  background: #F00;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <app-header>...</app-header>
  <div id="empty-state">
    .....
  </div>
</body>
```

You can also simply absolutely position your elements. Simply account for the height of app-header and offset #empty-state by this height. Like this:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
app-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
#empty-state {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #F00;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<app-header-layout>
  <app-header>
    .....
  </app-header>
  <div id="empty-state">
    .....
  </div>
</app-header-layout>
```